# MySQL Partitioning - Error by Primary key and Unique records

Tags: mysql, partitioning

i've a large table with about 2Mln records, and i want to partition it.

I've the id column as PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT int (and it must to be always UNIQUE).
I've a column "theyear" int(4) and i want to partition BY RANGE from 2016 to 2050, because most of Query use a WHERE statement getting 1 year at time.

Making the partitioning i get an error saying that the "theyear" key must be with PRIMARY KEY, so i've edited the primary key doing a multicolumn key PRIMARY (id, theyear).

It's all OK, but my "id" columns isn't UNIQUE anymore, because it checks "theyear" columns too...
So if I insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, theyear) VALUES (1, 2016);
INSERT INTO table (id, theyear) VALUES (1, 2017);
```

it says NO ERROR, because the UNIQUE check both id and theyear.

How can implement partitioning without lose UNIQUE on "id" column?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add a separate `unique` constraint against year?

Comment: I am basing this on the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html, but it seems to me that you don't need to change your primary key for a RANGE partition. All the example they use don't have a PRIMARY KEY. Am I missing something? Are you trying to partition by KEY() by mistake?

Comment: Why do you want to partition?  What query do you think will run faster?  Please provide that query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I will probably argue that a suitable index will as fast or faster then partitioning.  Perhaps the index would start with YEAR.  Hint: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: @RickJames i wanna use partitioning because my table is: 13,880,195  records (5.1 GiB)  right now ...

Comment: @JacquesAmar i'm trying to use KEY() but i get: "#1503 - A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function"

Comment: @StefanoVenneri - partitioning does not automatically improve performance, even for a 13M-row table.  CREATE?  SELECT?  I don't want you to go through the pain of converting your table only to find out that there was no advantage.

Comment: @StefanoVenneri, since your queries WILL use "theyear" in  it, partitioning by RANGE *will* help with large data, with the proper INDEX. Don't use KEY(), PARTITION BY RANGE (theyear) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2017),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2018),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2019),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2020) for example. You can add more partitions later, but harder. If your data is older, then obviously start with the oldest year.

Answer (score 0):

Since your queries WILL use `theyear` in it, partitioning by RANGE will help with large data, with the proper INDEX.

Don't use `KEY()` partitionning, keep your existing primary key

```
INDEX IDX_theyear(theyear)
```

and

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (theyear) ( 
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2017), 
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2018), 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2019), 
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2020)
```

for example. You can add more partitions later, but harder. If your data is older, then obviously start with the oldest year

Comment: I get: "#1503 - A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function" as I sayed in the question...